# Displaying submitted Table results in another Table on Same Page

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

Looking for a solution to an issue of a table that does **not** use `.innerhtml` to write directly below in text form, nor pop-up, nor jQuery, PHP, nor uses a form-type to collect data. document.write is preferred and not alternative method such as `<div>` tags.

```
<body>
    <table id="resultTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>
        Full Name:
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FullName2" id="fname2" readonly>
     Member ID:
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="MemberID" id="mid1">
</table>
</body>
```

Button

```
<button id="push" onclick="acceptInput()">Submit</button>
```

Following of process method

```
function acceptInput()
{
    fullname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
     mid=document.getElementById('mid1').value;
}
```

Second table

```
  <table id="resultTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>
        Full Name:
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FullName2" id="fname2" readonly>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <th>
        Member ID:
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="MemberID2" id="mid2">
}
```

Input gather from table needs output as a table upon click-event on same page. How would one translate the existing second table so that it only appears **after** clicking the submit button on the same page by **replacing** first table as vanilla Javascript/html?